# How to Access markdown front matter properties from Nuxt 3 script

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, yaml-front-matter, nuxt-content

Let's say, I have built a document driven **Nuxt Content** project. There is a markdown content file `/content/about.md` with the following content:

```markdown
---
title: About Me
status: complete
layout: page
---
## This is a heading
```

In `/layouts/page.vue` file, I have the following code to render the content:

```js
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>{{ page.status }}</h1> <!-- it works -->
  <slot />
 </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { page } = useContent();

console.log(page.status); // but this doesn't work, shows 'page' as "undefined"
</script>
```

As mentioned in the code, I can't access the frontmatter property `status` from the `script setup` section but it's accessible inside the template `<h1>{{ page.status }}</h1>`.

How can I access this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `.value` to the `page`.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const { page } = useContent()
console.log(page.value.status)
</script>
```

[image]